# message to specific client using multi threaded server

Tags: java

I have a multi threaded server in which server is waiting for all possible clients to be connected.As soon as client is connected it sends an int(12345) to server and server reads and display it now server uses a specific IPaddress of a client using hash map architecture sends a message to that client to which ipaddress is matched.but my code is stuck in while loop and it isn't go to the function messagetospecificclient() and if it goes it displays null. Sorry for my bad English 
My code is
Server

```
public class ServerStart implements Runnable 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                HandleMultipleClients hmc=new HandleMultipleClients();
                hmc.connect();
                hmc.messagetospecificclients("172.20.3.122");
            } 
}
HandleMultipleClients
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package zeeshannisar210;



import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * @author Zeeshan Nisar
 */
public class HandleMultipleClients{
    Map<Integer, java.net.Socket> clients = new HashMap<Integer, java.net.Socket> ();
    Socket sock;
    ServerSocket serverSock;
     DataOutputStream dos;
     DataInputStream dis;
     String ip;

  public HandleMultipleClients()
  {

  }
  public void connect()
  {
      try
    {
        serverSock = new ServerSocket(2101);
        while (true) 
        {
            sock = serverSock.accept();
            clients.put(sock.getPort(), sock);
            dis=new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            int s=dis.readInt();
            System.out.print(s);
            messagetospecificclients(ip);


        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
  }
  public void messagetospecificclients(String ipaddress) throws IOException
        {

            System.out.print(ipaddress);

            for (Iterator<Integer> iter = clients.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
{
    int key = iter.next();
     System.out.print("ok1");
    ip=ipaddress;
     System.out.print(ip);
     System.out.print("ok2");

    java.net.Socket client = clients.get(key);

    InetAddress zee = client.getInetAddress();
    String s = zee.getHostAddress();
     System.out.print("ok3");
      System.out.print(s);
    if (s.equals(ipaddress))
            {
                System.out.print("ok4");
                dos =new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF("Some message");

            }
}
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HandleMultipleClients();
    }

}
Client code is
 public class messagefromserver implements Runnable 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                sock = new Socket("localhost",2101);
                System.out.println("Success");
                dos=new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeInt(12345);
//                Basicinfosend bis=new Basicinfosend(sock);
//                Thread t1=new Thread(bis);
//                t1.start();
//                Thread.sleep(1000);
//                Systeminfosend sis=new Systeminfosend(sock);
//                Thread t2=new Thread(sis);
//                t2.start();
//                Thread.sleep(1000);
//                Thread p = new Thread(new Process());
//                p.start();
                while(true)
                {
                    String s=dis.readUTF();
                    System.out.print(s);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your error would be a lot easier to fix if you log your exception rather than catching it silently. That's likely why your method is not being called

Comment: How can i log exception or can you kindly correct my code @Kon

Comment: Wherever you catch an exception `e`, call `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Sorry but it didnt solve my problem it still takes a null ipaddress

Comment: Are any exceptions logged? You should probably attach a debugger with your IDE and walk through the code to see what's happening incorrectly

Comment: can you just tell me how can i get out of while()true

Comment: can this is possible in threads ??? @Kon